Supabase sessions not working across multiple subdomains in next.js multi-tenanted App
I'm using Supabase in a Next.js app directory. The app is multi-tenanted, but the Supabase sessions only work for a single domain (in my case, app.domain.com where the auth happens). Is there any way to make it work on any subdomain and base domain?
Middleware code of my app
export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const url = req.nextUrl;

  // Get hostname of request (e.g. demo.vercel.pub, demo.localhost:3000)
  let hostname = req.headers
    .get("host")!
    .replace(".localhost:3000", `.${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ROOT_DOMAIN}`);

  // special case for Vercel preview deployment URLs
  if (
    hostname.includes("---") &&
    hostname.endsWith(`.${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_DEPLOYMENT_SUFFIX}`)
  ) {
    hostname = `${hostname.split("---")[0]}.${
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ROOT_DOMAIN
    }`;
  }

  const searchParams = req.nextUrl.searchParams.toString();
  // Get the pathname of the request (e.g. /, /about, /blog/first-post)
  const path = `${url.pathname}${
    searchParams.length > 0 ? `?${searchParams}` : ""
  }`;

  const supabase = createClient();

  NextResponse.next().headers.set("x-url", req.url);

  const userId = (await supabase.auth.getUser()).data.user?.id as string;

  const { data, error: userError } = await supabase
    .from(DB.USER)
    .select("*")
    .eq("id", userId)
    .single();

  const requestHeaders = new Headers(req.headers);

  // rewrites for app pages
  if (hostname == `app.${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ROOT_DOMAIN}`) {
    if (!data && !path.includes("/auth")) {
      if (userId) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/auth/onboarding", req.url));
      } else {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/auth", req.url));
      }
    } else if (data && path.includes("/auth")) {
      if (userId) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/auth/onboarding", req.url));
      } else {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", req.url), {
          headers: requestHeaders,
        });
      }
    } else if (
      userId &&
      path.includes("/auth") &&
      path !== "/auth/onboarding"
    ) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/auth/onboarding", req.url));
    }

    const blogId = path?.split("/")[2];
    // Send blog subdomain to the request headers
    requestHeaders.set("x-blog-id", blogId);

    return NextResponse.rewrite(
      new URL(`/app${path === "/" ? "" : path}`, req.url),
      {
        headers: requestHeaders,
      }
    );
  }

  // if request is for assets (.png, .svg, .jpg), rewrite to original path
  if (path.startsWith("/assets")) {
    return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL(path, req.url));
  }

  // rewrite root application to `/home` folder
  if (
    hostname === "localhost:3000" ||
    hostname === process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ROOT_DOMAIN
  ) {
    return NextResponse.rewrite(
      new URL(`/home${path === "/" ? "" : path}`, req.url)
    );
  }

  requestHeaders.set("x-url", req.url);

  // rewrite everything else to `/[domain]/[slug] dynamic route

  // Before that, we need to check if the domain exists in the database and if it's active or not

  const subdomain = hostname.split(".")[0];

  const { data: blog, error } = await supabase
    .from(DB.BLOG)
    .select("*")
    .eq("subdomain", subdomain)
    .single();
  if (!blog) {
    console.error("Error fetching blog:", error);
    return NextResponse.rewrite(
      new URL(`/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ROOT_DOMAIN}/404`, req.url)
    );
  }

  // Send blog subdomain to the request headers
  requestHeaders.set("x-blog-subdomain", subdomain);

  return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL(`/${hostname}${path}`, req.url), {
    headers: requestHeaders,
  });
}

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Go to app.domain.com
Log in with Supabase auth
Try to access other subdomains or the base domain
Sessions don’t persist across different domains


You need to configure your cookie to be a wildcard e.g. domain.com. It looks like you might not have set it manually so it's defaulting to the current domain app.domain.com. See a comment on their github - https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/27283#issuecomment-2170478242
